# Reledmac: footnote position problem

Tags: horizontal-alignment, footnotes, reledmac

I am trying to have footnotes over three columns using reledmac package.
However, I don't understand how to get footnotes correctly positioned : it looks like this :

```
-----------------------------------------------
footnote 1                               footnote 4
                      footnote 3
footnote 2
```

where footnote3 vertical alignment is somewhere in the middle between 1 and 2. I want it to be aligned with footnote 1 and 4.

Any idea ?

Thank you,

Pen

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,textwidth=12cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{reledmac}
\arrangementX[A]{threecol}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[2] \footnoteA{pouet}\footnoteA{pouat}\footnoteA{pouit}\footnoteA{pouot}

\end{document}
```

Comment: it is a bug in reledmac, I am looking for it

Answer (score 3):

The version 2.9.0 of reledmac, just send on CTAN, fix this bug.

Now you should obtain

[image: Footnote output]

Comment: Hum, unfortunately, still doesn't work : /

Now it goes

--------------
                2                  4
1           
                3

which is even weirder...

Comment: I think you have dowloaded the version 2.9.0. It is send now, and you must wait 24 h to dowload it on CTAN.

Comment: cf http://ctan.org/pkg/reledmac which tells you the version is 2.8.2.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, I'll try again tomorrow then :)

Comment: I have added a screenshot of footnote output.

Comment: Perfect, looking forward to it !

Comment: dear @Penangol : could you make test and validate the question if ok ?